# How to use IF condition in AWS Api gateway mapping templates. can i use if condition without using foreach?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

`#if($inputRoot.objectType == 'Test'), "TableName": "StudentTests", #else,"TableName": "UserActions", #end`

if use if condition i got an error in postman link
 ## "__type": "com.amazon.coral.service#SerializationException" ##

Answer (score 7):

The way I understand your question I would do :

```
#if($inputRoot.objectType == "Test")
    #set($tableName = "StudentTests"
#else
    #set($tableName = "UserActions"
#end

{
    "TableName": "$tableName",
    "Key": ...
}
```

Comment: Probably needs quotes: `"TableName": "$tableName",`

Comment: Do you have a link to documentation for #if #set etc.?

Comment: Here you are : https://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.0/vtl-reference.html#ifelseifelse-output-conditional-on-truth-of-statements